# Get null as a default for integer types

Tags: c#, .net, binary-search-tree, sortedset

An algorithm from Leetcode Discussion uses Binary Search Tree to hold a range of values from an input array to check if this array contains values that are different at most by t, and their indexes are at most k far from each other.

**JAVA**:

```
public boolean containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(int[] nums, int k, int t) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0 || k <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    final TreeSet<Integer> values = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int ind = 0; ind < nums.length; ind++) {

        final Integer floor = values.floor(nums[ind] + t);
        final Integer ceil = values.ceiling(nums[ind] - t);

        if ((floor != null && floor >= nums[ind])
                || (ceil != null && ceil <= nums[ind])) {
            return true;
        }

        values.add(nums[ind]);
        if (ind >= k) {
            values.remove(nums[ind - k]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am struggling to make it work in C#. This code doesn't work as long as `LastOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault` methods return 0 as a default. How to work around to get `null` as a default?

**C#**:

```
public bool ContainsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(int[] nums, int k, int t)
{
    if (nums == null || nums.Length < 2 || k < 1) return false;

    SortedSet<long> set = new SortedSet<long>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        long l = (long)nums[i];

        long floor = set.LastOrDefault(n => n <= l);
        long ceil = set.FirstOrDefault(n => n >= l);

        if ((l - floor <= t) || (ceil - l <= t))
            return true;

        set.Add(l);
        if (i >= k) set.Remove((long)nums[i - k]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to declare your set with nullable longs

```
var set = new SortedSet<long?>();
```

Or you could just not use the `FirstOrDefault` and do something like:

```
var greaterOrEqualToOne = set.Where(n => n >= 1);

long? ceil = greaterOrEqualToOne.Any() ? greaterOrEqualToOne.First() : null;
```

Yet another way, cast them to `long?` first:

```
long? ceil = set.Select(n => (long?)n).FirstOrDefault(n => n >= 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use nullable long to get null on LastOrDefault

```
SortedSet<long?> set = new SortedSet<long?>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve int/long/... values including null, then you need to user [Nullable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

And in your source code will be:

```
 SortedSet<long?> set = new SortedSet<long?>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are technically correct (use nullable types on your set)

```
SortedSet<long?> set = new SortedSet<long?>();
```

However, in order to ever receive null value from `FirstOrDefault`/`LastOrDefault` you need to pass the `int?[] nums` to your method, because you fill your set by casting

```
long l = (long)nums[i];
```

which won't get you null value from int array even when casted to nullable `long?`.

In other words - your method needs to get nullable array in order to work with null values.

And if you won't ever be working with nulls on provided array why not just iterate from `i = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast int/long it to nullable type (?) as other users have stated and then use `DefaultIfEmpty` to create a default collection that contains null if the collection turns out to be empty.

```
SortedSet<long?> set = new SortedSet<long?>();

long? floor = set.Where(n => n <= l).DefaultIfEmpty().LastOrDefault();
long? ceil = set.Where(n => n >= l).DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That code does not compile. The `DefaultIfEmpty` is also unnecessary since `OrDefault` will do that for you already (i.e. return `null` if there are no matching elements from the `Where`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare int,long... values as NULL, you need to declare like this:

```
int? empId;
if(empId is null)
{
    // do this
}
else
{
    //do this
}
```

In the same way you have to use:

```
SortedSet<long?> sortedSet = new SortedSet<long?>();
```